# google authentication pop up not working using firebase in android development

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-signin

while doing a project...i did an authentication with a google account. but it's not working

**MainActivity.kt** in this activity I have implemented authentication uisng firebase but when i click the button no popup is showing

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    companion object{
        private const val RC_SIGN_IN = 120
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        // Configure Google Sign In
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        binding.gbutton.setOnClickListener{
            signIn()
        }
   }
    private fun signIn() {
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            val exception = task.exception
            if(task.isSuccessful){
                try {
                    // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                    val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
                    Log.d("SignInActivity", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.id)
                    firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
                } catch (e: ApiException) {
                    // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                    Log.w("SignInActivity", "Google sign in failed", e)
                }
            }
            else{
                Log.w("SignInActivity", exception.toString())
            }
        }
    }

    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d("SignInActivity", "signInWithCredential:success")
                    val intent = Intent(this,ActivityGoogleSigninBinding::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()

                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.d("SignInActivity", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)

                }
            }
    }
}
```

Gradle scripts and buttonID (using binding, XML file in layout) are done correctly
I have also checked logcat but couldn't found any error

Please help

Comment: The way you are trying to sing-in with Google is deprecated. I think this **[repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebase/auth)** might help. As you can see, you should use ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>. Besides that, are you getting some errors? As "it's not working" doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: I am very new to android i have tried using ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> but got an error in MainActivity,kt. Could you please provide me the solution code for the above one